# How to configure 2 interfaces without losing Internet connection?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dhcp

I am using Hyper-V for my Linux lab.

I have Ubuntu Server 16.04 which contain 2 network cards, shown in the system as 2 interfaces.

**eth0**: Configured to get IP address from DHCP server (my D-Link router provides internet access).

**eth1**: Configured as static IP for my internal network.

This is the `/etc/network/interfaces` file that I edit:

```
# Primary Network interface
Auto eth0
Iface eth0 inet DHCP

# Internal Network interface
Auto eth1
Iface eth1 inet static 
address 192.168.1.1 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
gateway 192.168.1.254 
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254
```

After I finish to edit the configuration file and reboot, I lose my Internet access.

Even if I try to ping to 8.8.8.8 from eth0 (with `ping -I eth0 8.8.8.8`), it fails.

When I delete the internal network interface from the configuration file and reboot, my internet connection gets restored.

What am I doing wrong? How can I configure my machine so that the eth0 device will use for internet access only, and the eth1 will use for my internal network?

Comment: shouldn't "Autu eth0" and "Autu eth1" be *Auto*? Is that a typo?

Comment: It was typo. Still have the problem

Comment: What does ifconfig look like for your eth0 dhcp?

Comment: Check out `ifenslave` just search for it on Google. I think this will help you out with what you want to do.

Comment: almost 3 years, yet: I would remove gateway definition of eth1. DHCP should send a gateway to eth0, and unless you have more remote network behind eth1 (e.g. 192.168.111.X), gateway definition routing is useless. system **knows** that IP like 192.168.1.X should be send to eth1, and all other to eth0.

Comment: Are both interfaces on the same physical network? What IP address do you get when you only use eth0 and what are the gateway address and net mask.  I suspect you might be creating a conflicting network configuration for 192.168.1.0/24 on both interfaces

Comment: Check your capitalisation. `Auto` should be `auto`, `Iface` should be `iface`

Answer (score 0):

can you tell the version of ubuntu server?
If you are sure that you are getting settings from dhcp on eth0 you could try reading the output from:
ifconfig /a

just to be sure i'd do:

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

Add below to `interfaces` file

```
auto eth0

allow-hotplug eth0

iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1

iface eth1 inet static

address 192.168.1.1 

netmask 255.255.255.0 

gateway 192.168.1.254
```

And then run:

`sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

And add:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.254 

nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Finally run:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install hv-kvp-daemon-init linux-tools-virtual linux-cloud-tools-virtual`

or you can read here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager#Using_NetworkManager_on_the_command_line

and type nmcli help

Comment: Thank you all for your quick response. I tried Malkavian suggestuin but it didn't help. After remove default gateway from eth1 - my Internet connection came back. Is there any way to set the eth0 gatway as my primary and the eth1 gateway as secondary gateway?

Answer (score 0):

im not sure about it, came across this when i was reading other related eth0 setting

[ip route with two default gateways](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144272/ip-route-with-two-default-gateways)

maybe can help you

Comment: This is probably the correct answer, however, it should be a comment.  Until you have enough rep to comment, you should focus on providing complete answers.  But like I said, most likely, he has 2 default gateways in his routing table for 0.0.0.0, which isn't going to work.